# How to improve dll loading time .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a dll and its size is 4 mb. The issue is when I call the dll it is taking 6 - 7 sec. Anybody has same issue. please suggest any solution.

I referred this dll in an asp.net web application. On a button click event I instantiate a class from this dll, here it is taking 6-7 sec.

Please note that at local it is working fine, but on the production server(Windows Server 2008 R2) I facing this issue.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: How you load that dll?

Comment: How are you measuring that? Faster hard-drive? Bigger CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on many things commonly how you code. if you use ants profiler it can tell you what method or object  is taking your memory and consuming time. for further please read these posts

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3980/Dll-Profiler-in-C
2. [Which .NET performance and/or memory profilers will allow me to profile a DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430047/which-net-performance-and-or-memory-profilers-will-allow-me-to-profile-a-dll)
3. [Any tool to detect which dll is leaking memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591931/any-tool-to-detect-which-dll-is-leaking-memory)